# Triying to make a form but not able to make a new line automatically when creating a new entry

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, visual-web-developer

In the last section of my JavaScript function, `element.appendChild` doesn't work properly to insert a `<br>` element after each text input. The text inputs are instead displayed inline, not on a new line like the three existing inputs.

```html
<div id='reference'>
        <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Company Name' size=40 /><br>
        <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Who to Contact' size=40 /><br>
        <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Contact Information' size=40 /><br>
    </div><br>
    <input type=button value="Add New Reference" onClick=" 
  element=document.getElementById('reference');
  newLine=document.createElement('br');
  newInput=document.createElement('input');
  newInput.placeholder='Company Name';
  newInput.size=40;
  newInput.id=company;
  newInput.name='refer[]';
  newInput.type='text';
  newInput1=document.createElement('input');
  newInput1.placeholder='Who to Contact';
  newInput1.size=40;
  newInput1.id=company;
  newInput1.name='refer[]';
  newInput1.type='text';
    
  newInput2=document.createElement('input');
  newInput2.placeholder='Contact Information';
  newInput2.size=40;
  newInput2.id=company;
  newInput2.name='refer[]';
  newInput2.type='text';
    
  element.appendChild(newInput);element.appendChild(newLine);
  element.appendChild(newInput1); 
  element.appendChild(newInput2);
    "/>
```

Comment: cannot find `txtarea`? please, you explain more.

Comment: "Doesn't work properly" is not very specific. It would help if you explain in your question, what you are trying to achieve, and what your code is doing instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're creating a single reference to a single `<br>` element with `newLine = document.createElement('br');`, you need to create a separate reference for each one, or clone the one you make, or even easier just stick `element.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );` where you want the new lines. This snippet should work for you

```js
function customFunction(){
  element=document.getElementById('reference');
  newInput=document.createElement('input');
  newInput.placeholder='Company Name';
  newInput.size=40;
  newInput.id=company;
  newInput.name='refer[]';
  newInput.type='text';

  newInput1=document.createElement('input');
  newInput1.placeholder='Who to Contact';
  newInput1.size=40;
  newInput1.id=company;
  newInput1.name='refer[]';
  newInput1.type='text';

  newInput2=document.createElement('input');
  newInput2.placeholder='Contact Information';
  newInput2.size=40;
  newInput2.id=company;
  newInput2.name='refer[]';
  newInput2.type='text';

  element.appendChild(newInput);
  element.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
  element.appendChild(newInput1);
  element.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
  element.appendChild(newInput2);
  element.appendChild( document.createElement('br') );
}
```

```html
<div id='reference'>
  <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Company Name' size=40 /><br>
  <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Who to Contact' size=40 /><br>
  <input id='company' type=text name='refer[]' placeholder='Contact Information' size=40 /><br>
</div>
<input type=button value="Add New Reference" onClick="customFunction()"/>
```

That said, wouldn't it just be easier to edit your form markup a little bit, clone the whole `reference` div, and append it to a field container `div`?

```js
function customFunction(){
  fields = document.getElementById('fields');
  clone  = document.getElementById('reference').innerHTML;
  row    = document.createElement('div');
  
  row.innerHTML = clone;
  
  fields.appendChild( row );
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <div id="fields">
    <div id="reference">
      <input id="company" type="text" name="refer[]" placeholder="Company Name" size="40" /><br>
      <input id="company" type="text" name="refer[]" placeholder="Who to Contact" size="40" /><br>
      <input id="company" type="text" name="refer[]" placeholder="Contact Information" size="40" /><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Add New Reference" onClick="customFunction()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! thanks a lot, i was bothering over it for quite a while now.

Comment: My pleasure, glad to help! If you wouldn't mind clicking the checkmark to mark this question as answered when you're able? Thanks, and best of luck!